# 3 unknowns and 1 equation

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Find the values of a and b if,

$$\frac{a}{x+3}-\frac{b}{x+2}=\frac{3x-2}{(x+3)(x+2)}$$

The answer shows to simultaneously solve these two equations:

> $a-b=3$
> $2a-3b=-2$

But I have no idea how in the world to get these two equations.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The unknowns are just $a$ and $b$ and equality is supposed to hold for *every* $x$ (except $-2$ and $-3$). So you actually have infinitely many equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that this equation is true for *any* value of $x$. This is how you get more than one equation: you plug in more than one value of $x$.

We have that $\frac{a}{x+3} - \frac{b}{x+2} = \frac{a(x+2) - b(x+3)}{(x+3)(x+2)}$, so we know $a(x+2)-b(x+3) = 3x-2 \implies (a-b)x + (2a - 3b) = 3x-2$. Because this should work for any value of $x$, we have that $a - b = 3$ and $2a - 3b = -2$.

Comment: But, it isn't true for any value of $x$ it doesn't work with $x = -3$ or $x = -2$

Comment: @Enigsis, correct, both sides of the original equality are not defined when the denominator is zero. This you can't change. However, the 2 sides are equal for all other values of $x$ other than those where the fraction is not defined.

Comment: Yes, but, the correct answer is this but, saying that $x \neq -2 \land x \neq -3$

Answer (score 2):

The standard method for this is called [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).

Basically you’re finding rational functions with denominators of lower degree by using the [method of equating coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equating_the_coefficients)  which is itself a useful and powerful technique.

Ets1331 showed how to do it in this case.